# How to use onKeyUp event in TextField in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am using flutter to make a simple application.
In the below code, when TextBox changed event is fired then I call the method named updateTitle().

But I have to call the same method updateTitle(), when key is up, as we use in javascript and other languages too.

```
              TextField(
                controller: titleController,
                style: textStyle,
                onChanged: (value) => updateTitle(),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Title",
                    labelStyle: textStyle,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    )),
              ),
```

Comment: what do you mean with "onkeyup"? On mobile 'onkeydown' and 'onkeyup' doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @RicardoBRGWeb, Currently, I am using onChange to enable my button.
I have to enable the button if textField is not empty. i.e. if someone, types something.

Comment: But the onchanged event is fired everytime the user type a new character in the field, just like "onkeyup" would work. You need to listen to this event, test if it is not empty and enable the button, using setstate to change its state. I will post an answer with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your use case, the `onChanged`works just like `onkyeup` would work. Everytime that the user tap a new character in the textfield, it is fired.

In order to enable/disable a button you should listen to this event, do the test to see if the field isn't empty, modify a variable that will handle the button state, and call `setState()`.

This is just a sample code. Not tested, but should work as is.

```
class _SoAnswerState extends State<SoAnswer> {

    bool _buttonActive = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ...

        TextField(
            controller: titleController,
            style: textStyle,
            onChanged: (value) => updateButtonState(value), // onChanged return the value of the field
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Title",
                labelStyle: textStyle,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                )
            ),
        ),

    ...
    }

    void updateButtonState(String text){
        // if text field has a value and button is inactive
        if(text != null && text.length > 0 && !_buttonActive){
            setState(() {
                _buttonActive = true;
            }
        }else if((text == null || text.length == 0) && _buttonActive){
            setState(() {
                _buttonActive = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: add more information about the events

In JavaScript, the `onkeyup` event handler fires when the user releases a key that was previously pressed. When the user press and release a key inside a text field, the text field value changes. The `onChanged` listener in Flutter fires when the text field value changes. When working with a typing interface, where the user uses a tradicional keyboard, it is not a good idea to listen to all the changes of a text field, because the user can press and hold a key, leading the application to repeat the onchanged event too many times, once for every character repetition. That's not the case with a mobile interface, where the user (usually) can't press and hold a key.

Comment: you're absolutely right. Thanks for answer. Please tell why Onchange and onkeyup will work same here?

Comment: CondingbyRaj I have added some more information to the answer, about the events.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo BRGWeb, your answer is really useful.